# How do I group a pandas column to create a new percentage column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've got a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
mydict ={
        'person': ['Jenny', 'Jenny', 'David', 'David', 'Max', 'Max'],
        'fruit': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Orange'],
        'eaten': [25, 75, 15, 5, 10, 10]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict) 

    person fruit   eaten
    Jenny  Apple   25
    Jenny  Orange  75
    David  Apple   15
    David  Orange  5
    Max    Apple   10
    Max    Orange  10
```

Which I'd like to convert into:

```
person  apple_percentage  orange_percentage
Jenny   0.25              0.75
David   0.75              0.25
Max     0.50              0.50
```

I'm guessing that I'll have to use `groupby` in some capacity to do this, but can't figure out a clean Pythonic way of doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with division by `sum`s:

```
df = df.pivot('person','fruit','eaten').add_suffix('_percentage')
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
fruit   Apple_percentage  Orange_percentage
person                                     
David               0.75               0.25
Jenny               0.25               0.75
Max                 0.50               0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is pandas' crosstab:

```py
(pd.crosstab(index = df.person, 
            columns = df.fruit, 
            values = df.eaten, 
            aggfunc = 'mean', 
            normalize='index')
   .add_suffix('_percentage')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
 
        Apple_percentage  Orange_percentage
person
David               0.75               0.25
Jenny               0.25               0.75
Max                 0.50               0.50
```

You could also use the `pipe` method, although in this case, it does not make the code clearer (which defeats the purpose of the `pipe` function):

```py
(df.assign(eaten = df.groupby('person')
                     .pipe(lambda grp: df.eaten / 
                                       grp.eaten.transform('sum'))
           )
  .pivot('person', 'fruit', 'eaten')
  .add_suffix('_percentage')
  .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
        Apple_percentage  Orange_percentage
person
David               0.75               0.25
Jenny               0.25               0.75
Max                 0.50               0.50
```

Answer (score -1):

Can stack and unstack() and agg

```
    df=df.set_index(['person','fruit']).stack().unstack('fruit').add_suffix('_percentage')#)

df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')



 fruit person  Apple_percentage  Orange_percentage
0      David              0.75               0.25
1      Jenny              0.25               0.75
2        Max              0.50               0.50
```